# Vienna - groceries opening hours during weekend

Tags: food-and-drink, shopping, austria, vienna

In which hours are the groceries opened during weekend in Vienna?

I will arrive there Saturday before noon, I'd like to know if I should take the food for 2 days with me, or can I expect to buy some supplies being there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

06:00 to 18:00 at most on Saturdays, not opened at all on Sundays. There are exceptions for stores in airports and train stations. Here's a [list of branches with special opening hours](https://www.billa.at/Metanavigation/Oeffnungszeiten/Oeffnungszeiten/dd_bi_subpage.aspx?folderId=137396) for Billa, a large supermarket chain.